# How is this JS code explained

Tags: javascript

I have a js file (requirejs api) which i am trying to understand, but unable to get any meaning

**First few lines:**

```
var requirejs,require,define;
(function(ba){
    function J(b){
        return"[object Function]"===N.call(b)
        }
        function K(b){
        return"[object Array]"===N.call(b)
        }
        function z(b,c){
        if(b){
            var d;
            for(d=0;d<b.length&&(!b[d]||!c(b[d],d,b));d+=1);
        }
    }
    function O(b,c){
    if(b){
        var d;
        for(d=b.length-1;-1<d&&(!b[d]||!c(b[d],d,b));d-=1);
    }
}
```

the parent page loading this js has a call to method **require()** but i dont see any such function definition in entire file. And then how is argument ba treated? is "b" coming from ba? Is this file made of obfscation? all functions are named like a() , b() etc

Comment: This is a minified version of the script file. Minification minify all the variables name to the shorter ones.

Comment: what about ba & b, "ba" is not used later

Comment: Where is ba? I am not able to find any ba

Comment: @treemonster19 `ba` is a `global` context, which is passed in the very last line of the sources: https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/blob/master/require.js#L2045.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a minified version of RequireJS. Just open the full version with comments:

http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.6/comments/require.js

During the minification, in order to save bytes, variable names are often replaced with the short ones. For instance, here `J(b)` refers to method `isFunction(it)` and `K(b)` to `isArray(it)`, while `z(b,c)` looks like `each(ary, func)` and `O(b,c)` is `eachReverse(ary, func)`.

Comment: oh thanks, i understand why they minify to save data transfer over network. but still there is no function like require()

Comment: @treemonster19 There is: https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/blob/master/require.js#L1746.